# Stop JQueryUI Calendar clearing Asp.net Textbox on postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, calendar, postback

This one is starting to bug me and Googleing doesn't seem to be turning up working results for me.

I have a JQueryUI Calendar on an ASP.NET Textbox which always clears the text when a button causes a postback.

The following Javascript creates the calendar

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: '../images/cal16.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/y' });
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/MM/y');
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ yearRange: '1900:2323' });
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '0');
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', '-90y');
        $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'yearRange', '1900:2323');
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDatePicker" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

And I also have the following on the Page_Load method

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.ButtonRegister, typeof(string), "CalendarScript", @"
                            $(function () {
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({
                                    changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true,
                                    showOn: 'both',
                                    buttonImage: '../images/cal16.gif',
                                    buttonImageOnly: true
                                });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/y' });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/MM/y');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ yearRange: '1900:2323' });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '0');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', '-90y');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'yearRange', '1900:2323');
                            });", true);
```

I have tried a number of different options to try and repopulate the textbox but none seem to work.

- putting the text value in a session and populating the textbox at the page load
- adding the value as an attribute value
- adding 
  "var jobValue = document.getElementsByName('TextBoxDatePicker')[0].value;
                                  $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('setDate', jobValue);"
  to the javascript.

I think the issue is to do with the RegisterStartupScript wiping the values each time but I am not sure how I get round that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in stopping the textbox values being cleared on a postback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve this one myself.
Below is what I did, hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

It turns out that the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript was the issue, it was wiping the values each time after the page load. So to combat this I changed the script on the Page_Load method to the following...

```
string CalendarScript = @"
                            $(function () {
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({
                                    changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true,
                                    showOn: 'both',
                                    buttonImage: '../images/cal16.gif',
                                    buttonImageOnly: true
                                });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'ddMy' });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'ddMy');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker({ yearRange: '1900:2323' });
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '0');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', '-90y');
                                $('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('option', 'yearRange', '1900:2323');";

        if (IsPostBack && TextBoxDatePicker.Text != String.Empty)
            CalendarScript += "$('#TextBoxDatePicker').datepicker('setDate', '" + TextBoxDatePicker.Text +"');";

        CalendarScript += "});";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.ButtonRegister, typeof(string), "CalendarScript", CalendarScript, true);
```

Essentially I am setting the value of the datepicker to be equal to that of the textbox if it has a value. So anytime there is a postback it will retain that value.